# HttpClient POST using request method error on Firefox: event is not defined

Tags: angular, firefox, xmlhttprequest, angular-httpclient

How come this error happens after changing a working `this.http.post` to `this.http.request`, to be able to track upload progress, and why only on Firefox? Am I not creating the Request object correctly?

No request is being sent (nothing in network tab).

The argument `file` can originate from the `files`-property of an `input[type=file]`, or from a `drop` event, doesn't make a difference. I have logged & verified that `file` is a valid File object in both cases.

No problems with Chrome, Edge and IE11. This works on all browsers with otherwise identical circumstances: `return this.http.post('/filesystem/upload', formData, { withCredentials: true })`

Tried `withCredentials:false` and `reportProgress:false`, no difference.

Angular: 5.2.5

Browser: Firefox 58.0.2 Windows

```
  private sendFile(file: File) {
    this.progress$.next(0);
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file, file.name);
    formData.append('name', file.name);
    const req = new HttpRequest('POST', '/filesystem/upload', formData, {
      withCredentials: true,
      reportProgress: true
    });
    return this.http.request(req).pipe(
      map((e: HttpEvent<any>) => {
        switch (e.type) {
          case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
            const percentDone = Math.round(100 * e.loaded / e.total);
            this.progress$.next(percentDone);
            break;
        }
        return event;
      }),
      last()
    );
    //  Works:
    //  return this.http.post('/filesystem/upload', formData, { withCredentials: true });
  }
```

Error:

```
ReferenceError: event is not defined
Stack trace:
FileBrowserComponent.prototype.sendFile/<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:427:13
MapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:82:22
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:97:13
MergeMapSubscriber.prototype.notifyNext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:156:13
InnerSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/InnerSubscriber.js:27:9
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:97:13
HttpXhrBackend.prototype.handle/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:2407:13
Observable.prototype._trySubscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:178:20
Observable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:166:88
subscribeToResult@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/util/subscribeToResult.js:32:20
MergeMapSubscriber.prototype._innerSub@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:143:18
MergeMapSubscriber.prototype._tryNext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:140:9
MergeMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:123:13
Subscriber.prototype.next@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:97:13
ScalarObservable.prototype._subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/observable/ScalarObservable.js:53:13
Observable.prototype._trySubscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:178:20
Observable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:166:88
MergeMapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:97:16
Observable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:163:13
MapOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/map.js:60:16
Observable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:163:13
LastOperator.prototype.call@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/operators/last.js:43:16
Observable.prototype.subscribe@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:163:13
Observable.prototype.toPromise/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:292:13
ZoneAwarePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:875:29
Observable.prototype.toPromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/Observable.js:290:16
FileBrowserComponent.prototype.upload/</<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:505:46
step@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:49:18
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:30:53
__awaiter</<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:24:15
ZoneAwarePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:875:29
__awaiter<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:20:12
FileBrowserComponent.prototype.upload@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:453:16
FileBrowserComponent.prototype.fileInputChange/</<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:435:50
step@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:49:18
verb/<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:30:53
__awaiter</<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:24:15
ZoneAwarePromise@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:875:29
__awaiter<@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:20:12
FileBrowserComponent.prototype.fileInputChange@webpack-internal:///./src/app/shared/file-browser/file-browser.component.ts:432:16
View_FileBrowserComponent_14/<@ng:///SharedModule/FileBrowserComponent.ngfactory.js:348:27
handleEvent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:13759:115
callWithDebugContext@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:15268:39
debugHandleEvent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:14855:12
dispatchEvent@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10174:16
renderEventHandlerClosure/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:10799:38
decoratePreventDefault/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/esm5/platform-browser.js:2680:53
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17
onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/core/esm5/core.js:4952:24
ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17
Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28
ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:24
invokeTask@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1517:9
globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1543:17
file-browser.component.ts:319:8
```

**Edit:**
Because of `HttpXhrBackend.prototype.handle/<@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@angular/common/esm5/http.js:2407:13` in the stack trace, I went straight to that file and found the name `event` mentioned in just two places. Added console.logging to both and nothing is logged except the first `Editing the right file`. So what is this `event` then? Something internal in `XMLHttpRequest`? What's happening!?

```
console.log('Editing the right file'); // << gets logged
var onDownProgress = function (event) {
    // We never get this far
    if (!event) {
        console.log('onDownProgress event is null');
    }
    console.log('onDownProgress event is not null', event);
// ...
var onUpProgress = function (event) {
    // We never get this far either
    if (!event) {
        console.log('event undefined');
        return;
    }
    console.log('event is defined', event);
// ....
```

**Edit:**

Added [issue in GitHub](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22730).

Answer (score 1):

It was all because of  `return event` instead of `return e` in my map call. What a well-spent half a day. Why does the compiler and other browsers let something like this slip, and then Firefox of all catches it (and gives a greatly useful stack trace)?

Comment: Answer to why my IDE or compiler didn't raise red flags was a global variable called event is declared in lib.dom.d.ts